# Post Twitter message from iPhone app with OAuth

Tags: iphone, post, twitter, oauth, message

How can I post a message on Twitter from my app using OAuth authentication?
I'd like to post an invariable message with a variable link...
How can I do this?
Any source? Any tutorials?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OAuth library such as:

http://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer
http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

There are various tutorials out there like:

http://www.jaanuskase.com/en/2010/01/an_example_iphone_twitter_app.html

It can be tricky, especially since twitter has changed since some of the popular iPhone implementations were written, but this will give you a place to start.

Comment: I followed these posts but I didn't understand how to import these library where I'll use them... Can you help me?

Comment: The first link I posted is designed to have all of its source included in the project.  I like to put it in its own folder.  Its at github, so to download it go to your project directory in the command line and type "git clone http://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer.git".  There is a readme included that will tell you which build settings to change.  I feel that OAuth is a lot easier to integrate with a web-app than a mobile app at this moment.